# Force 1st point of pointinterval to be plotted

Tags: plot, gnuplot, intervals

I tried to plot graph using the pointinterval command and I would like the 1st point of my data to be plotted which is not the case for the hot side of my first plot. Indeed we see the purple dashed line but no point at the bottom left corner (around y+=0.35).
[image: Hot side: the first points start at y+=1 and not at y+=0.35 as expected.]

My code involves for loop and is displayed below:

```
plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] myDataFile(i) u (column(1)):(column(6)/word(UTAUS_ch,i)) w lp pointinterval 2 pt myPointtype(i) ps myPointsize(i) dt myDashtype(i) lt myLinetype(i) lw myLinewidth(i) lc rgb myLinecolor(i) title myTitle(i)
```

If I plot with pointinterval 1 we see that those points exist (see picture below). [image]

How can I force the first point to be plotted with pointinterval?
Is that possible to plot half of my points every 2 points and the other part every 2 points but with an offset of 1 point?

Comment: how does your data look like? just the first few lines. Are there maybe headers or comment lines?

Comment: My data are composed of: 119 lines of headers in the following way
"#column 1: COORDINATES  
 #column 2: TEMPERATURE..."  

and 151 lines of data (with 119 columns).

Comment: thanks. well, @Ethan explained how `pointinterval` actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you will be able to do what you want using the `pointinterval` property. It is designed so that the offset of the initial point increases by one for each plot drawn, with the intention of reducing the chance that point symbols from successive plots will overlap.  This is exactly opposite to what you are trying to do.

Therefore I suggest not plotting each dataset `with linespoints pi N`. Instead plot each dataset twice, once `with lines` and once `with points` using a filter in the `using` specifier like this:

```
 plot FOO using 1:2 with lines, '' using ((int($0)%N) ? NaN : $1) : 2 with points
```

The filter (int($0)%N ? NaN : $1) suppresses all points whose line number is not evenly divisible by N.  This is essentially what the `pointinterval` property does, except that `pointinterval` skips out-of-range points and otherwise unplottable points rather than strictly using the line number as an index.

**Edit** If individual offset values are required because x-coordinates are not consistent:

```
array offset[N] = [1,1,2,-1, and so on]
plot for [i=1:N] \
    MyDataFile(i) using 1:2 with lines, \
    '' using (((int($0)+offset[i] % N) ? NaN : $1) : 2 with points
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan. 

I tried this but the same issue appears: `N=2 plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] myDataFile(i) u (column(1)):(column(2)/(word(UTAUS_ch,i))) w lines, for [i=1:words(FILES)] myDataFile(i)  u ((int($0)%N) ? NaN : (column(1)):(column(2)/(word(UTAUS_ch,i))) w points`

I also tried to suppress the headers in order to only have plottable point but I still got the issue.

Comment: If your data files do not have have consistent x-coordinates for a given line number, that is a separate problem.  You can adjust the starting point for a particular file by adding an offset to the filter: `using ( (int($0)+offset)%N ? NaN : $1)` but it sounds like you might need a different offset for each file.  In that case you could make offset into an array and empirically load it with the appropriate values.